# Show/Hide with CSS transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to use the following two css classes to show/hide elements with transition effects-

```
    .hidden{
        opacity: 0;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
        transition: all 2s;
    }

    .shown{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        height: auto;
        transition: all 2s;
    }

    //JS code to toggle classes -
     $("#cancelLogin").click(function(){
         $('form.login').toggleClass("shown").toggleClass("hidden");
         $('.circles').toggleClass("concealed").toggleClass("shown");
     });
```

`.shown` works fine, but no transition happening while adding `.hidden` class. Any idea?

Comment: You aren't adding the `hidden` class. `concealed` is being added but it has no properties defined.

Comment: @Sarah that's a typo. I updated that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `height: 0` on the `hidden` class, this will execute firstly and you won't see any transition during the hiding process. You can achieve this with multiple tricks and ways, like the [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) and do stuff in a certain order or add a delay to your height adjustment and make it execute after the transition happens.

You can use the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) method to make this happen.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div")
const button = document.querySelector("button")

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (div.classList.contains("hidden")) {
    div.classList.remove("hidden")
    div.classList.add("shown")
    div.style.height = 'auto'
  } else {
    div.classList.remove("shown")
    div.classList.add("hidden")

    setTimeout(() => {
      div.style.height = 0
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
.div {
  transition: all 2s;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.shown {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">div</div>
<button>change visibility</button>
```

**NOTE:** To avoid CSS rule duplication it is always better to assign the `transition` to the element itself instead of classes which will be triggered based on different actions.

Comment: Use `transitionend` event listener instead of `setTimeout` to make it less convoluted.